# How to block all IP addresses in a range?

Tags: networking, ip, nginx

In nginx, I know that to block all IPs in the range  5.121.66.xxx, one can 
use this directive:

deny 5.121.66.0/24;

Now, I'd like to know how a range like 5.121.yyy.xxx (where yyy in 1-255) can be blocked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's wrong with substituting to the instruction you have for 5.121.66.xxx the following

```
     5.121.0.0/16
```

It is called [Classless InterDomain Routing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing), it comes in handy quite often.